# I am using TKinter and it says that there is a float conversion error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using TKinter and it says that there is a float conversion error with lines 14-18. I am trying to make the compound interest formula.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry
master = Tk()
master.title('Compound Interest Calculator')
master.geometry('1000x1000')
Label(master, text="Principal Amount").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Time").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Interest rate").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="Compounded (per year)").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Final").grid(row=4)
prin = Entry(master)
time = Entry(master)
ir = Entry(master)
c = Entry(master)
A1=float(prin.get())         #error in this line and the 4 lines that follow it
A2=float(time.get())
A3=float(ir.get())
A4=float(c.get())
final = A1 * (((1 + (A3/A4)) ** (A4*A2)))
prin.grid(row=0, column=1)
time.grid(row=1, column=1)
ir.grid(row=2, column=1)
c.grid(row=3, column=1)
final.grid(row=4, column=1)
master.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: You create some Entries, and then you *immediately* try to get their contents as floats.  How could there possibly be any contents yet, the user has had no chance at all to type anything?  You need to do the `.get()`s and calculation in response to a button click, once the user has finished entering their data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `.get()` he takes the value of the entry and return, since it's still empty, he trows the error. To fix that you should add an button with a callback, when the button is pressed he will get the values and do the math. Try the code bellow, should work fine:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button

def get_values():
  global master

  A1 = float(prin.get())
  A2 = float(time.get())
  A3 = float(ir.get())
  A4 = float(c.get())
  final = A1 * (((1 + (A3/A4)) ** (A4*A2)))

  Label(master, text=str(final)).grid(row=4, column=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  master = Tk()
  master.title('Compound Interest Calculator')
  master.geometry('1000x1000')

  Label(master, text="Principal Amount").grid(row=0)
  Label(master, text="Time").grid(row=1)
  Label(master, text="Interest rate").grid(row=2)
  Label(master, text="Compounded (per year)").grid(row=3)
  Label(master, text="Final").grid(row=4)

  prin = Entry(master)
  time = Entry(master)
  ir = Entry(master)
  c = Entry(master)
  prin.grid(row=0, column=1)
  time.grid(row=1, column=1)
  ir.grid(row=2, column=1)
  c.grid(row=3, column=1)

  Button(master, text="OK", command=get_values).grid(row=5, column=1)
  master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much I really appreciate it.